# Insert date data in table in snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have created a table and now i'm trying to insert the data. But i'm getting an error: Numeric value '30D' is not recognized.

Can you help me with this?

```
`CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE date_dim (
  D_DATEKEY NUMBER(8,0) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
 D_DATE TEXT(18),
 D_DAYOFWEEK TEXT(8),
 D_MONTH TEXT(9),
 D_YEAR NUMBER(4,0),
 D_YEARMONTHNUM NUMBER(6,0),
 D_YEARMONTH TEXT(7),
 D_DAYNUMINWEEK NUMBER(1,0),
 D_DAYNUMINMONTH NUMBER(2,0),
 D_DAYNUMINYEAR NUMBER(3,0),
 D_MONTHNUMINYEAR NUMBER(2,0),
 D_WEEKNUMINYEAR NUMBER(2,0),
 D_SELLINGSEASON TEXT(12),
 D_LASTDAYINWEEKFL BOOLEAN,
 D_LASTDAYINMONTHFL BOOLEAN,
 D_HOLIDAYFL BOOLEAN,
 D_WEEKDAYFL BOOLEAN
 );

INSERT INTO date_dim(D_DATEKEY, D_DATE, D_DAYOFWEEK, D_MONTH, D_YEAR, D_YEARMONTHNUM, D_YEARMONTH, D_DAYNUMINWEEK, D_DAYNUMINMONTH, D_DAYNUMINYEAR, D_MONTHNUMINYEAR, D_WEEKNUMINYEAR, D_SELLINGSEASON, D_LASTDAYINWEEKFL, D_LASTDAYINMONTHFL, D_HOLIDAYFL, D_WEEKDAYFL)
SELECT 
TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(date, 'YYYYMMDD')) AS D_DATEKEY,
TO_CHAR(date, 'Month DD, YYYY') AS D_DATE,
TO_CHAR(date, 'Day') AS D_DAYOFWEEK,
TO_CHAR(date, 'Month') AS D_MONTH,
TO_CHAR(date, 'YYYY') AS D_YEAR,
TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(date, 'YYYYMM')) AS D_YEARMONTHNUM,
  TO_CHAR(date, 'MonYYYY') AS D_YEARMONTH,
DATE_PART('dow', date) AS D_DAYNUMINWEEK,
TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(date, 'DD')) AS D_DAYNUMINMONTH,
TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(date, 'DDD')) AS D_DAYNUMINYEAR,
  TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(date, 'MM')) AS D_MONTHNUMINYEAR,
 TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(date, 'WW')) AS D_WEEKNUMINYEAR,
CASE
WHEN TO_CHAR(date, 'MMDD') = '0101' THEN 'New Year''s Day'
WHEN TO_CHAR(date, 'MMDD') = '0704' THEN 'Independence Day'
WHEN TO_CHAR(date, 'MMDD') = '1225' THEN 'Christmas Day'
ELSE ''
END AS D_SELLINGSEASON,
CASE WHEN DATE_PART('dow', date) = 6 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS D_LASTDAYINWEEKFL,
CASE WHEN TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(date, 'DD')) = TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(LASTDAYOFMONTH(CAST(date AS DATE)), 'DD')) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS D_LASTDAYINMONTHFL,
  CASE 
WHEN TO_CHAR(date, 'MMDD') = '0101' THEN 1 -- New Year's Day
WHEN TO_CHAR(date, 'MMDD') = '0704' THEN 1 -- Independence Day
WHEN TO_CHAR(date, 'MMDD') = '1225' THEN 1 -- Christmas Day
ELSE 0
END AS D_HOLIDAYFL,
CASE WHEN DATE_PART('dow', date) IN (0, 6) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS D_WEEKDAYFL
 FROM (
SELECT DATEADD('day', CAST(seq4() AS NUMBER), '1997-12-30') AS date
FROM table(generator(rowcount => 3652))
); `
```

I have written this query and facing errors. Not getting what does 30D not recognised means.

Comment: You are trying to insert a character data value into number column. 30D is the value

Comment: I didn't get what you mean.

Comment: Run the select statement without the insert and make sure the values are the correct datatypes

Comment: isnt it self explanatory ? Youre trying to insert non numeric data into a numeric field.  Convert the field to string.

Comment: Now i'm getting: SQL compilation error: syntax error line 30 at position 30 unexpected 'AS'. syntax error line 31 at position 2 unexpected 'FROM'.
(Only running select statement)

Comment: SELECT 
TO_CHAR(date, 'DDD') AS D_DAYNUMINYEAR,
TO_CHAR(date, 'WW') AS D_WEEKNUMINYEAR
FROM (
SELECT DATEADD('day', CAST(seq4() AS NUMBER), '1997-12-30') AS date
FROM table(generator(rowcount => 1))
);

Comment: these are the two columns that causing the issue.  start removing columns until you find the ones

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
    TO_CHAR(date, 'DDD') AS D_DAYNUMINYEAR,
    TO_CHAR(date, 'WW') AS D_WEEKNUMINYEAR
FROM (
    SELECT 
        DATEADD('day', CAST(seq4() AS NUMBER), '1997-12-30') AS date
    FROM 
        table(generator(rowcount => 1))
);
```

30D |  WW

> Numeric value '30D' is not recognized.

Your statement is trying to cast a field that has non-numeric values to Numeric `30D`